# Protonvpn wireguard config does not work on openwrt router 22.03.05

Tags: openwrt, wireguard

I could successfully install protonvpn openvpn config files and could connect to internet but speed is very low so I tried wireguard but....

I have free proton vpn account - just testing waters ...

I downloaded one of the free and one std server config for wireguard for touter

I am entering correct keys etc but not getting any data trasnfer...I see handshake and some bytes in rx and tx but that is it...nothing else..can not open any website nothing...

I am using 22.03.05 openwrt version on my tplink archer a7 v5 - one thing I noticed that protonvpn provides public key only for peer and for interface provides only private key - but this later openwrt version compulsorily ask me to enter public key as well along with private key - under general setting.

I can not leave blank ..so what should I enter in public key space ? (protonvpn does not provide it)

I tried various Youtube video and tried to troubleshoot but nothing worked